# Nested serializer upto a level in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have `models.py`

```
class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = True, blank = True)

class AttributeValue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = True, blank = True)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True, related_name = 'attribute_value')

class Product(models.Model):
    attribute_value = models.ManyToManyField(AttributeValue, blank = True, related_name = 'products')
```

`serializers.py`

```
class AttributeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Attribute
        fields = ['id', 'name']

class AttributeValueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    attributes = AttributeSerializer(read_only = True, many = True)
    class Meta:
        model = AttributeValue
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'attributes']

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    attribute_value = AttributeValueSerializer(many = True, read_only = True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['attribute_value']
```

I am trying GET request for Product model where i expect data to look like this

```
product1 = {
    attribute1 = [
         {'id': 'someid', 'name':'some_name'}, {'id': 'someid', 'name':'some_name'}
    ],
    attribute2 = [
         {'id': 'someid', 'name':'some_name'}, {'id': 'someid', 'name':'some_name'}
    ]
}
```

But i am getting like this. Also i got `Type error` when i added `attribute` instead of `attributes` in `AttributeValueSerializer` serializer class

```
product1 = {
    "attribute_value": [
          {'id': 'someid', 'name':'some_name'}, 
          {'id': 'someid', 'name':'some_name'}
    ]
}
```

Is there anything i am doing wrong ? Thanks in advance.